# Best way to store multiple variables in separate file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a large project that I'm working on and in the project I use a lot of different variables in multiple threads and files.

What is the best and most "common" way to store all these variables?

To clearify, they will not be changed by the program or during running a program, the only problem is that multiple threads uses the same variables and it gets messy to change them in different files all the time.

My current thought is to use a .py file but never run it, just store all the variables. As follows:

```
#file with variables

a = 3 #text describing a
b = 12 #text describing b
c = "hello" #text describing c
d = 3323 #text describing d
e = True #text describing e
```

And then access them by importing the file.

Is this an efficient way or is there a better one?

Comment: Is efficient for STATIC variables for only READ, like connections to database, api, server information. Not reccomended if you will change values between threads. For threads use Objects

Comment: Your thought is correct, usually you have a file with all constants which you can import whenever you need it. There is a [naming convention for constants](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants), in full uppercase with underscores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a .py file and imported variables from the file fore some time now, works great. Probably the best edit I have done to my program, makes changing variables super easy.